# Is instant coffee an impurity when you add it to water?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have this question for chemistry, but can't know whether it is an impurity or not, please help.

Comment: Is your water still pure after you add coffee to it?

Comment: Isn't this more of a linguistics question?

Answer (score 2):

An impurity is pretty much by definition something that is present that is not desired. If you have deliberately added something, in this case instant coffee, then it is not an impurity but a component, something you intend to have present.